# CSS nesting: inherit from whom?

Tags: css, inheritance, nested

here is a fiddle with the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/c2exs2f7/3/

How does the second "blue" stay like the first instance (it should have `color: white`) **without** changing the HTML structure?

**HTML**

```
<div class="blue">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="label">blue</div>
    <div class="yellow">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="label">yellow</div>
        <div class="blue">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="label">blue</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
// Skip until...

div {
  border-radius: .25em;
  padding: .5em;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
}

// ...here:

.blue {
  background-color: hsl(220,100%,50%);

  .content {
    color: white;
  }
}

.yellow {
  background-color: hsl(60,100%,50%);

  .content {
    color: hsl(0,0%,10%);
  }
}
```

**EDIT #1**
Thank you guys for these fast responses!
I am working on a grid system where I am able to nest different grid systems (with different CSS values).

Comment: Having a jsfiddle is a nice addition, but you should always include the important parts with question itself. A question (and also an answer)  should always be self-contained, because external links could become invalid.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I am pretty new to this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectors `.yellow .content` and `.blue .content` have the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) (20 in this case), therefore the selector that appears later in the stylesheet will override the first one  due to the cascading nature of a stylesheet. In this case, the selector `.yellow .content` is overriding `.blue .content`, which is why the nested `.blue` element is black.

One quick solution would be to select nested `.blue` element with the selector `.blue .blue`:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/jzbjd655/)

```
.blue,
.blue .blue {
    background-color: hsl(220,100%,50%);

    .content {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

An arguably better approach would be to only select direct `.content` children elements using the [child selector, `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators):

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/eyj0Lmry/)

```
.blue {
    background-color: hsl(220,100%,50%);

    > .content {
        color: white;
    }
}

.yellow {
    background-color: hsl(60,100%,50%);

    > .content {
        color: hsl(0,0%,10%);
    }
}
```

Based on your comments, the ordering/layering of the elements may vary. An alternative solution would be to set the `color` property on the `.blue`/`.yellow` element and then set the `color` property of the children elements to `inherit`:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/wxL3epcv/) - this seems to work for all variants.

```
.blue {
    background-color: hsl(220,100%,50%);
    color: white;

    .content {
        color: inherit;
    }
}

.yellow {
    background-color: hsl(60,100%,50%);
    color: hsl(0,0%,10%);

    .content {
        color: inherit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this first approach, but it won't work if the HTML markup is "yellow > yellow > blue": https://jsfiddle.net/jzbjd655/1/. Is there a better way to achieve this without declaring every single possibility of mixing blue and yellow in a specificy order?

The second example with the use of child selector is for this simple example great, but I am not sure if I can guarantee that there won't be some "layer"-div between mother and child.

Comment: Great new solution. Is there a similar way to achieve my goal without giving  .blue a color of white? If I have a grid system, this solution of yours wouldn't be that great. In your example, it is okay that .blue and .yellow get a color. It won't be okay, if in my real-life project a parent like ".row" gets the values of the ".column" width properties.

Answer (score 1):

See https://jsfiddle.net/c2exs2f7/4/

What I did was to enforce inheritance only for the child `content` classed DIV, not the entire descendance.

Applying the immediate children operator `>` in the SCSS makes the `.content` div to consider only its immediate parent color.

Go on and try nesting more `DIV`s, you will see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Not with inherent anyway. Because the second blue will inherent from the yellow. So if u want all blue always have white letters and yellow always black letters. Why not just put:

```
.blue { color: #fff; }
.yellow { color: hsl(0,0%,10%); }
```

And you won't need the ".content" wrapper.

Comment: This is a great idea. My problem is that this code of mine is some simplification of a grid system.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue where the HTML nesting varies and so it's not possible to make more specific selectors due to overwhelming complexity and non-DRY code.

Here's the solution I came to:

https://jsfiddle.net/cg0u8v1s/

Basically, a systematic approach to the class names is key so you can use a CSS attribute selector reliably (although I'd recommend a more unique naming convention than "color-" as it's too generic.).

**Example:**

```
.color-blue {
  &,
  [class*="color-"] &,
  [class*="color-"] [class*="color-"] & {// Only needed if you want a 3rd level of nesting to work.
    background-color: blue;

    .content {
      color: skyblue;
    }
  }
}

.color-yellow {
  &,
  [class*="color-"] &,
  [class*="color-"] [class*="color-"] & {// Only needed if you want a 3rd level of nesting to work.
    background-color: yellow;

    .content {
      color: brown;
    }
  }
}
```

This will output selectors that become more specific with nesting without the need for non-DRY code or having to use !important.

**The CSS output will look like this:**

```
.color-blue,
[class*="color-"] .color-blue,
[class*="color-"] [class*="color-"] .color-blue {
  // code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the most inner label has no siblings, you can do the following:

```
.blue .label:only-child {
  color: white;
}
```

The `:only-child` CSS pseudo-class represents an element without any siblings